# How do I convert bitmap image to TensorImage on Android?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

It's my first time to post question. I've been building a object classification program using tensorflow lite for Android device(Java). I already made the same function program by using Python and Keras so I converted the model to tflite form and I used it on android. But the result is quite different than I got in Python. I suspect the image processing method before inference was incorrect.

In Python, the image process before inference is below:

```
img = cv2.imread(image_dir)/255.  
img = cv2.resize(img, (64,64), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
img_list.append(img)
img_list = np.array(img_list).astype(np.float32)

model.predict(img_list, batch_size=512, verbose=0)
```

In Android(Java), the image process before the inference is below:

```
Mat img = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img, true);

Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY); //to grayscale

Size size = new Size(64,64);
Imgproc.resize(img, img, size, Imgproc.INTER_AREA); //resize

Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.width(), img.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Utils.matToBitmap(img, dst); //convert to bitmap

int imageTensorIndex = 0;
DataType imageDataType = tensorFlowLiteModel.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType(); //tensorFlowLiteModel is interpreter which also inferences (loaded from XXXX.tflite)

TensorImage tfImage = new TensorImage(imageDataType);
tfImage.load(dst);

int probabilityTensorIndex = 0;
int[] probabilityShape =
                tensorFlowLiteModel.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape();
DataType probabilityDataType = tensorFlowLiteModel.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType();
outputProbabilityBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(probabilityShape, probabilityDataType);

tensorFlowLiteModel.run(tfImage.getBuffer(),  outputProbabilityBuffer.getBuffer().rewind())
```

It actually worked and showed result but the result is different from Python(Keras).
I guess the image process before inference was wrong.
I also know image process using ByteBuffer but it was didn't work because of OOM(Out of memory) so I want to use TensorImage class.
If you know how to deal with this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Have you normalized the pixels of bitmap as in python?